# How to install multiple certificates using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the below script for one certification.

But need to modify it, in order to install multiple certificates.

```
$script = {
    $file = ( Get-ChildItem -Path  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\newCert.cer )
    $file | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalUser\Root
    echo $file
    }

invoke-command -Credential $clientCred -ComputerName $ClientIP -ScriptBlock $script
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, just chucked it in a foreach loop over every file on the desktop with the extension of **.cer** if you want to change the folder, change the first line in the foreach loop `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\`

```
 foreach ( $file in ( Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ -filter *.cer )) {
        $script = {
            $file.fullname | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalUser\Root
            echo $file
        }

        invoke-command -Credential $clientCred -ComputerName $ClientIP -ScriptBlock $script
 }
```